# Multiplying a constant with the value of a register in ARM without the MUL instruction

Tags: arm, multiplication

I need to multiply the value of a register(r1) by 16385 and store the result in the same register without using the MUL instruction in a single line of code.

I know that using LSL instruction will multiply a value by a power of 2 but since I am trying to multiply by an odd number I don't see how that would work. I saw another similar question where someone was asking how to multiply a*17 and the answer that was provided was ADD r1, r1, r1 LSL #4. I don't understand why this would result in multiplying the value by 17, and how I would know I am multiplying by the correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add r1, r1, r1, lsl #14`

It's equivalent to `r1 = r1 + (r1<<14);`

Also, `add r1, r1, r1, lsl #4` is equivalent to `r1 = r1 + (r1<<4);` which again, is equivalent to `r1 = 16*r1 + r1;`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do know how this works, from grade school math.

Multiply in binary is 10 times simpler than decimal.

If I have the binary number abcd where a,b,c,d are each individual bits, either a one or a zero each.   And I want to multiply that by 5 decimal which is 0b101 binary.

```
   abcd
*  0101
=========
```

and fill it in, long multiplication if you will

```
     abcd
*    0101
=========
     abcd
    0000
   abcd
+ 0000
=========
```

binary makes it easier because either you add in a shifted version of the number or you add in zero for each step.

You can also use other grade school math

x * 5 = x * (2^2 + 2^0) = (x * 2^2) + (x * 2^0) = (x*4) + x = (x<<2) + x

In your case:

16385d = 0x4001 = 0x0100000000000001 = (1<<14) + (1<<0)

Comment: note that arm has nothing to do with this it is just basic math.  Once you have reduced it down then the syntax gets language/target specific to implement that math.  A question like this in school is more than half about recognizing the basic math part then once that is sorted out implementing the result in the target language/syntax.